# Too many arguments in function call error

Tags: c++, function

I am working on creating an object of a class and have written a constructor and am working on adding an object.  I believe that I have enough variables for the function but it is saying that I have too many arguments.  I do not understand why it is saying this.

I have tried redoing my constructor and code but am continuing to run into the same error.  I eventually want to be able to clone the object but I am not sure how to do that either.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Animal {
public:
    Animal() {};

    Animal(string uAName, string uASize, string uAColor, int uANumLegs)
        : aName(uAName), aSize(uASize), aColor(uAColor), numLegs(uANumLegs) {};

    void printAnimal(Animal) {
        cout << "Your animal is: " << aName << endl;
        cout << "The animal size is: " << aSize << endl;
        cout << "The animal Color is: " << aColor << endl;
        cout << "The animal has " << numLegs << " legs" << endl;
    }

    virtual Animal* clone() { return (new Animal(*this)); }

    void aClone(Animal* nAnimal) {
        Animal* cal = nAnimal->clone();

    }

private:
    string aName = "";
    string aSize= "";
    string aColor = "";
    int numLegs = 0;


    };



int main()
{
    Animal newAnimal();

    string uName = "Bear";
    string uSize = "Large";
    string uColor = "Black";
    int uLegs = 4;

    newAnimal(uName, uSize, uColor, uLegs);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Animal newAnimal();` is a *function declaration*, not a *variable declaration* (due to ["most vexing parse"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). Thus calling `newAnimal(uName, uSize, uColor, uLegs);` is trying to call a 0-parameter function with 4 values, hence the error.

Even if you fixed that declaration (by removing the parenthesis), your code would still fail to compile, since `newAnimal(uName, uSize, uColor, uLegs);` would then be trying to invoke `operator()` on the `newAnimal` object, but your class does not implement `operator()`.

To invoke your class constructor, you need to change your `main()` to this instead:

```
int main() {
    string uName = "Bear";
    string uSize = "Large";
    string uColor = "Black";
    int uLegs = 4;
    Animal newAnimal(uName, uSize, uColor, uLegs);
}
```